# 503 Error when calling WCF web service but only by my Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service that I wrote and is working fine in a production environment. However I am getting an error is a new test environment.

The service is being accessed by a Windows service running on the same server. When it attempts to send a request it receives a 503 response code with a message saying the service is unavailable.

However I have confirmed that the service is reachable by browsing to the auto-generated service information page and the WDSL. I can also send requests to it using SOAPUI.

All three clients (the app, the browser, and SOAPUI) are using the same base URL and all running locally on the same server.

I don't understand how the service can be unavailable to one client but be available to the others.

Both the web service and client (windows service) are written in c# in Visual Studio 2017 targeting .Net Framework 4.0 and running on a Win server 2016.

--Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Any 5XX ranges are generated on the server side, which may mean that you have a configuration problem when deploying the server. 
If it works fine on your development machine, then pay close attention to setting anything like the IP address or other communication port that will be used.
Probably caused by a stopped application pool. Just make sure to restart the correct app pool to get your website working again.
You can check the documentation on the 503 Service Unavailable error: what it is and how to fix it.
https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/http-503-how-to-fix-website-errors/ 
https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/503-service-unavailable 
[Service Unavailable 503 + The HTTP service located at http://localhost/ProductsService/Service.svc is too busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793226/service-unavailable-503-the-http-service-located-at-http-localhost-productss)

Comment: I am aware of what 503 means. My problem is that the serve is not actually unavailable. I am looking for an answer specific to this situation.

Comment: Probably caused by a stopped application pool. Just make sure to restart the correct app pool to get your website working again. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17314911/17218587. You can check the link provided in the answer to find the solution.